# Which free ORM tools supports SQL Server 2000 database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, orm, sql-server-2000

In my project I want to use an ORM tool, but my database runs on SQL Server 2000. I can't use Entity Framework and Linq. I can just use ado.net. I want to know which ORM tools support my needs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the requirements? Just simple table to object mappings? If yes, try https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/. It works on a SqlConnection and is not specific to any sql server verison.

Comment: NO I WANT QUERING  WITH IT  NOT JUST MODELING IT

Comment: your link dosent open for me i cant see it can you check it

Comment: Just google "dapper dot net" if you have issues clicking on the link. And you should probably fix your capslock key.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik Data Access (FREE)

[Introducing Telerik Data Access](http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/data-access-introduction)

[How to: Create Domain Model Based on MS SQL 2000 Database](http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/developers-guide/database-specifics/microsoft-sql-server/data-access-tasks-mssql-howto-connect-sql2000-database)

[Consuming a Model - CRUD](http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/getting-started/getting-started-root-working-data)

[CRUD Operations - Overview](http://docs.telerik.com/data-access/developers-guide/crud-operations/developer-guide-crud-overview)

[image]

```
using System.Linq;
using OpenAccessModel;

namespace ConsumerProject
{
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           using (EntitiesModel dbContext = new EntitiesModel())
           {
               // Add a new Category.
               Category newCategory = new Category();
               newCategory.CategoryName = "New Category";
               dbContext.Add(newCategory);

               // Get the first Category using LINQ and modify it.
               Category firstCategory = dbContext.Categories.FirstOrDefault();
               firstCategory.CategoryName = firstCategory.CategoryName + "_Updated";

               // Commit changes to the database.
               dbContext.SaveChanges();

               // Use LINQ to retrieve Category with name 'New Category'.
               Category categoryToDelete = (from c in dbContext.Categories
                                            where c.CategoryName == "New Category"
                                            select c).FirstOrDefault();

               // Delete the 'New Category'from the database.
               dbContext.Delete(categoryToDelete);

               // Commit changes to the database.
               dbContext.SaveChanges();
           }
       }
   }
}
```

**YES! LINQ SUPPORT MS SQL 2000 Database**